# A truncated exponential distribution as a sum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Given a random variable $X$ folloiwng truncated exponential distribution on interval $[0,1]$ with parameter $\lambda$, i.e.,
$$f(x)= \frac{\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda}}\cdot e^{-\lambda x}.$$ It is direct to derive its expectation $\beta =E[X] = \frac{1}{\lambda}- \frac{1}{e^\lambda-1}$.

Now given $\beta_1$,$\beta_2$, $a_1$, and $a_2$, satisfying $a_1+a_2=1$, and $\beta_1+\beta_2=\beta$.

My problem is: Can we find two independent random variables $X_1$, $X_2$ distributed separately on interval $[0,a_1]$ and $[0,a_2]$, and satisfying $E[X_1]=\beta_1$, and $E[X_2]=\beta_2$, such that

$$X=X_1+X_2?$$

Comment: I assume you meant $f(x) = \frac\lambda{1-e^{-\lambda}}\cdot e^{-\lambda x}$ and corrected it in the post.

Comment: the sum of two exponentials with the same rate parameters is gamma(2, $\lambda$). So, if you create one exponential from 0 to 1/2 and the other from 1/2 to 1, that should work but check it by comparing the gamma to your first example. Also, notice that to make those respective rv's, for the first one, you'll need the scaling factor in the bottom to be  $(1-exp^{-\lambda \frac{1}{2}})$ and , for the second one you need to integrate the density from 1/2 to 1 in order to get the scaling factor for the truncation.

Comment: The support of these two random varialbes needs to be $[0,a_1]$ and $[0,a_2]$. Also for the second random variable  on $[1/2,1]$ you mentioned, its expectation is obviously larger than $\beta_2$.

Comment: I removed the inappropriate [tag:geometric-probability] tag. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.